# Bad operand types for binary operator+

Tags: java

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){
        int[] A={1,2,3,4,5,6},sum=0;
        for(int i=2;i<=4;i++)
        {
            sum=(sum+A[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("the sum is"+sum);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
HelloWorld.java:7: error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
             sum=(sum+A[i]);
                     ^
  first type:  int[]
  second type: int
2 errors
```

I know that the code works well with all the 8 primitive data types. But why isn't it working here? My array is also of integer type.

Comment: decalre `int sum=0;` not `int [] sum=0;`

Comment: You neglected to mention that there's an error on the line where you're *declaring* `sum` too...

Answer (score 0):

`sum` should be an `int`, not an `int[]`.

Change

```
int[] A={1,2,3,4,5,6},sum=0;
```

to

```
int[] A={1,2,3,4,5,6};
int sum=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`sum` is declared as `int[]`, do this instead:

```
int[] A={1,2,3,4,5,6};
int sum = 0;
```

You can declare multiple fields in a single field declaration ([JLS 8 § 8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3)) but in this case:

> More than one field may be declared in a single FieldDeclaration by using more than one declarator; the **FieldModifiers and UnannType apply to all the declarators in the declaration**.

i.e. the type applies to all fields in the declaration statement.

You can also add an initializer to a variable name in such a statement, but in your case the second initializer `=0` doesn't match the type of the FieldDeclaration statement, and so the compiler wouldn't let you compile the statement `int[] A={1,2,3,4,5,6},sum=0;`. Your IDE is probably telling you about that error too with a message like `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to int[]`, but you haven't seen it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `sum` as an arrayof `int`s, but initializing it to an int value, that's the problem.

This line won't compile

```
int[] A={1,2,3,4,5,6},sum=0;
```

it should be like this

```
int A[]={1,2,3,4,5,6},sum=0;
```

or

```
int[] A={1,2,3,4,5,6};
int sum=0;
```

By doing so, `A` is declaread as an array and `sum` as a primitive integer datatype.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] A={1,2,3,4,5,6},sum=0;
```

**Problem :**

The compiler treating `sum` as a integer array, not `int`. Since you declared beside of type `int[]`

**Solution:**

You'll be fine if you write

```
int[] A={1,2,3,4,5,6};
int sum=0;
```

**Enhancement :**

There is a short hand notation for writing `sum=(sum+A[i]);` That can be simply rewrite as

```
sum += A[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the complete error message:

> The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int

you define `A` and `sum` as `int[]`!

You have to change to:

```
int[] A={1,2,3,4,5,6};
int sum=0;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't sum a `int` value and an `array`. If you want your code to run you have to declare `sum` as `int`.
Your main method should be:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    int[] A={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=2;i<=4;i++)
    {
       sum=(sum+A[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("the sum is"+sum);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your sum is also of type `int[]` because of this line.

```
int[] A={1,2,3,4,5,6},sum=0;
```

You have to make `sum` of type `int` like so

```
int[] A={1,2,3,4,5,6};
int sum=0;
```